# LightingInput for Address not setting default Country Code

Tags: address, lightning-record-form

I am using the new Lightning:recordForm with a list of fields.

```
    <lightning:recordForm
     objectApiName="Account"
     recordTypeId ="{!v.rtTypeId}"
     fields="{!v.acctFields}"
     columns="2"
     mode="edit" 
     onload = "{!c.handleOnload}" />
```

One of the fields in the field list is BillingAddress, and it does correctly display the Billing Address fields as a compound address:

[image]

But as you will see, it doesn't default the value for Billing Country Code correctly. Looking in the onload logs, it is getting the value of US, just not the displayValue. I was thinking I could doing something like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221058/show-form-with-page-layouts-intercept-save-lightningrecordform-forcer) in the onload and set the default, but it isn't working:

```
 var response = event.getParams();
 var fields = response.record.fields;
 console.log(fields.BillingCountryCode.value); //US
 console.log(fields.BillingCountryCode.displayValue); //null
 fields.BillingCountryCode.displayValue = 'United States';//doesn't work
```

Anyone know how to either a) get the default to work, or b) set the displayValue to United States?

Comment: just to confirm its not person account record type?

Comment: correct - regular accounts with record types

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that this is now a [know issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmFvQAK):